# Поиск и замена с учетом спецсимволов

Tags: bash, replace, sed

Требуется заменить часть строки

```
* * * * *
```

на

```
*/15 * * * *
```

(да, это крон - чтобы излишне часто не запускали нехорошие пользователи).

Первое значение присвоил переменной abuse, второе переменной норм.

Но как бы не бился, не получаю точного соответствия строки.

Пробовал:

```
abuse="\* \* \* \* \*" 
abuse2='\* \* \* \* \*'
abuse3='* * * * *'
abuse4="* * * * *"
```

Первые два примера выдают строку именно в таком виде, т.е. с символами экранирования, вторые два отдают список всех файлов-папок.

Соответственно и

```
find -type f  -exec sed -i /var/spool/cron/ 's/$ABUSE/$NORM/g' {} \;
```

не работает, выдавая

> extra characters after command

Подскажите решение, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
$ abuse='\* \* \* \* \*'
$ norm='*/15 * * * *'
$ sudo find /var/spool/cron/ -type f -exec sed -i "s,$abuse,$norm," {} +
```

---

замеченные у вас ошибки:

1. путь вы вставили явно не в то место команды.
2. если в аргументах команды `s` программы *sed* используется, например, символ <kbd>/</kbd>, то этот же символ, конечно, не может служить для разделения аргументов. я воспользовался символом <kbd>,</kbd>, как явно не входящим ни в один из аргументов.

Comment: Благодарю, всё работает.

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Переменные в bash подставляются только в двойных кавычках. Замените

```
 's/$ABUSE/$NORM/g'
```

на

```
 "s/$ABUSE/$NORM/g"
```

- [Variable Substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html)
- [Quoting Variables](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)

Comment: Объявление переменной в каком из вариантов будет верным? Т.к. при использовании ABUSE='* * * * *' получаю ошибку sed: -e expression #1, char 8: extra characters after command

Comment: проблема в слэше внутри norm. Решения два -- экранировать этот слэш или заменить в sed команде слэши на другой символ, как в ответе  alexander barakin